# LXDE Auto Login

Tags: lxde, auto-login

I have a VERY old kubuntu server that I had to install LXDE on in order to keep it going (before lubuntu was born).

I just upgraded it to 12.04 as I finally had a need for some more modern features.  Unfortunately I have no idea how to get auto login to the desktop working again.

I have found suggestions that the following files should be edited

```
/etc/lxdm/default.conf
/etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf
/etc/xdg/lxdm/lxdm.conf
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

to include something like

```
[base]
## uncomment and set autologin username to enable autologin
autologin=username
```

but none of these files exist on my system and I cannot find any promising alternatives.

Any suggestions on what I should try or where I should look next would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't have the following directories at all: /etc/lxdm/ , /etc/lightdm/ , /etc/xdg/lxdm/ or /etc/xdg/lxde/
I do have lxsession and openbox under /etc/xdg/ but these don't contain appropriate .conf files.

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the instructions found in the official [Lubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Boot_Install_Login#For_release_12.04_and_on_.28LightDM.29)

Quote:

> For release 12.04 and on (LightDM)
>
> You will need to create an /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with these contents: (do this as root)
>
> ```
> [SeatDefaults]
> autologin-user=<YOUR USER>
> autologin-user-timeout=0
> # Check https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/854261 before setting a timeout
> user-session=Lubuntu
> greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set it up for a guest user on lubuntu 14.04.
I found an answer that helped me:
http://www.htpcbeginner.com/enable-lubuntu-auto-login/

However the file mentioned there: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` does not exist in lubuntu 14.04.
But there is a file

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf`

This is the contents of the file that works for me:

```
[SeatDefaults] 
user-session=Lubuntu
autologin-user-timeout=0
allow-guest=true
autologin-guest=true
```

I have just still one nasty pop up error everytime when the system boots up:

```
No session id for PID $ACHANGINGNUMBERFOREVERYSESSION
```

And the screen locks after a couple minutes.
(Tried following the procedure in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession with the guest-prefs user, that user does not get the lockout anymore but the guest user does, even though the profile is soft-linked to the guest skeleton, maybe filerights, I will look into this and come back)

However this may still be usefull for someone, if you find a solution to get rid of that error, please mention it as well.