# Autologin on lubuntu 14.10

Tags: lubuntu, auto-login

How can I enable autologin on lubuntu 14.10?
I tried various method like this [LXDE Auto Login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426831/lxde-auto-login) but they don't work.

Comment: Did you encrypt your home folder when you installed Ubuntu? If so, autologin is disabled to protect the encrypted home folder.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Lubuntu Wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Boot_Install_Login#For_release_12.04_and_on_.28LightDM.29

you must

For release 12.04 and on (LightDM)

You will need to create an /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with these contents: (do this as root)

```
[SeatDefaults]

autologin-user=<YOUR USER>

autologin-user-timeout=0

user-session=Lubuntu

greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

It appears that what you have tried and say does not work is similar but not the same as this solution.

Comment: A comment on http://www.htpcbeginner.com/enable-lubuntu-auto-login/ says `From lubuntu 14.04, you should use this file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf for the seatdefaults, the syntax is the same.`  Turns out he's right.  At least for me anyway.