# Ubuntu mini auto login

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, auto-login

Installed Ubuntu mini (Ubuntu 18.04-mini.iso) and chose at the end **Lubuntu mini** package option.
Next issued

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core
```

in order to have a graphical interface.

Want to have auto login to my user account.
It seems that **/etc/lxdm/default.conf** should be edited in order to achieve that.
However, command

```
EDITOR=/usr/bin/leafpad sudoedit /etc/lxdm/default.conf
```

responds

```
sudoedit: /etc/lxdm/default.conf: editing symbolic links is not permitted
```

What should be done to edit **default.conf**?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1130769/231142

Comment: I think this still works on 18.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/426831/lxde-auto-login Newer versions are different since they no longer use LXDE

Comment: 1) Mine is a mini, I don't have that interface - must use command line.
2) @Organic Marble: Thanks, have finally found that the file to edit is /etc/lxdm/default.conf but I'm not allowed to edit it - get message "editing symbolic links is not permitted" which is strange.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this assumes your display manager is `lightdm`! I've no idea what comes on the mini iso.

From a stock 18.04 Ubuntu system overlaid with LXDE:

I created `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with these contents:

You will need to create an /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with these contents:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=<YOUR USER>
autologin-user-timeout=0

[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
```

It autologins in as YOUR USER nicely.